# If $x$ and $y$ are rational then is $x^y$ also rational?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, irrational-numbers

I can think of the counter example $x = 2$ and $y = 1/2$ but how would a proof to disprove this look like?

Comment: You have a counterexample! That's all a disproof needs.

Comment: The interesting question is the reciprocal.

Answer (score 12):

Providing a single counterexample suffices to prove that a conjecture is false, i.e.,providing a counterexample is all that's needed to disprove a conjecture.

You've done just that!

Answer (score 0):

$\underline{Theorem:}$ If $x, y \in \mathbb{Q}$ then not necessarily $x^y \in \mathbb{Q}$.

$\underline{Proof:}$ Suppose $x^y \in \mathbb{Q}$. Let $x = 2$ and $y = \frac{1}{2}$. Then $\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{Q}$, but that is a contradiction. RAA

Comment: Just curious: what does "RAA" stand for?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Reductio Ad Absurdum: Reducing it to  the absurd.

Comment: Thanks. This is the first time I've seen "RAA" at the end of a proof.

Comment: The more you know :)

Comment: Once you've written "Suppose $x^y\in\mathbb Q$" you're not allowed to continue with "Let $x=2$", because you have already introduced $x$ in your "suppose", which means that you're letting the opponent choose _any_ $x$ which satisfies your supposition.

Comment: How would I correctly say it @HenningMakholm?

Comment: @DonLarynx: Remove "Suppose $x^y\in\mathbb Q$".